# How to replace square bracket notation (abc['prop']) to dot notation (abc.prop) in JavaScript/Typescript easily?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am editing some code which has been written with a lot of unnecessary square bracket notations. For better understanding of the code, I want to convert stuff like `abc[3]['prop']["subprop"]` to `abc[3].prop.subprop`.

I can do this almost perfectly by doing text replacement in VSCode multiple times using regex `([\w_$][\w$_\d]*(?:(?:\[\d+\])+)?)\[["']([\w_$][\w$_\d]*)["']\]` to `$1.$2`.

But it would also be nice to convert `{ 'prop': value1, "prop2": value2 }` to `{ prop: value1, prop2: value2 }`.

Is there any way to accomplish both goals, perhaps a prettier/beautifier/formatter extension or utility?

Answer (score 3):

The [`dot-notation`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/dot-notation) rule for ESLint with the `--fix` option can automatically correct it.

[`quote-props`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quote-props) (which can also be auto-fixed) can also remove unnecessary quotes around properties, thanks Bravo.

Comment: would `quote-props` rule help with the second goal?

Comment: Thanks ! Though still trying to use ESLint. This is a salesforce project with a few javascript files. So I created `.eslintrc.yaml` as:
rules:
  dot-notation: ["error", {allowKeywords: false}]
  quote-props: ["error", "always"]